# How to set background image for disabled segment in UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I've tried to set color to disabled segment in UISegmentedControl. But not yet succeeded. I want to know that if it's possible to set background image for disabled segment in UISegmentedControl.

I've tried the following code but it's not working :

```
NSDictionary *attrs = @{ UITextAttributeTextColor : [UIColor lightGrayColor] };
[self.controlStatus setTitleTextAttributes:attrs forState:UIControlStateDisabled];

[self.controlStatus setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"] retain] forState:UIControlStateDisabled barMetrics:nil];
```

1st two lines are working. I'm able to set the color but not the background image or background color when disabled.

Is there any way to do this ??

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE:** You will have to do it the following way.

```
[[UISegmentedControl appearance] setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SegmentViewDisabled"]
                                    forState:UIControlStateDisabled
                                    barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Looks like you will encounter a bug from Apple's end if you set the divider image for disabled state though, found [here](http://openradar.appspot.com/11031502)

-------------------The below does not work--------------------

You can do it this way. Where SegmentViewDisabled is an image asset in your image assets catalog.

```
[self.controlStatus setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"SegmentViewDisabled"] forState:UIControlStateDisable barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

---

Comment: @swathykrishnan are you images in .png format? If not, add the extension to your imageNamed:@""

Comment: @swathykrishnan are your images in JPG or PNG? Also are you storing them in the project directly or using assets catalog?

Answer (score 0):

UISegmentControl has a Divider between two segments. By using the following code you can change the divider background.

```
[segmentedCtrl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"divider_selected.png"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[segmentedCtrl setDividerImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"divider_normal.png"] forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to customize the appearance of your segmented control beyond standard tinting, you might consider doing so using custom images. Since segmented controls have different metrics for portrait and landscape device orientations, remember to specify an appropriate image for each set of metrics.

You can set a background image for each control state of your segmented control using the backgroundImageForState:barMetrics: method. You should also specify divider images for each combination of left and right segment states to give selected or highlighted segments a different look than segments in a normal state, as shown here:

image1,image2,image3 are different images

```
    [mySegmentedControl setDividerImage:image1 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal  rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:barMetrics];

    [mySegmentedControl setDividerImage:image2 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected rightSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal barMetrics:barMetrics];

    [mySegmentedControl setDividerImage:image3 forLeftSegmentState:UIControlStateNormal rightSegmentState:UIControlStateSelected barMetrics:barMetrics];
```

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html)

Comment: The problem is, none of the answers here address a specific _segment_. From what I can tell, the background image for a given state is still the background of the entire segmentedControl, with no regard for the selected segment.